# Drawer navigator screens strange behavior

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation-v5, react-lifecycle-hooks

I'm using react-navigation v5 in my expo managed workflow project and the thing that I noticed is that every second time I visit a screen that is attached to a drawer navigator, lifecycle methods are not being invoked...

Here is the example:

```
- DrawerNavigator
  - Screen1
  - Screen2
```

The first time I visit "Screen1" **useEffect** hook is being invoked and all of my data is being fetched. **Once I navigate from it ( navigate to a "Screen2" ) and go back to "Screen1", nothing is happening ( data is not being fetched again )**... Is there something that I'm missing because I want on every visit of the "Screen*" my data to be restarted ( fetched again )?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the 'useFocusEffect' which will run everytime the screen is loaded.

You can find the reference here
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

useEffect doesnt work like that so when you come back to screen1 which is already mounted and in the stack the effect wont run.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This is exactly what I did and it works.